# View original kernel message timings from historical system logs

Tags: linux-kernel, journalctl

By default `journalctl` shows messages in the traditional system log format, including the CLOCK_REALTIME stamp, i.e. wall clock time (and calendar date).

However, this doesn't show accurate timestamps for kernel messages, if they were logged when journald wasn't running e.g. during boot or the suspend/resume procedure.  Most kernels nowadays default to enabling `printk.time`, so `dmesg` shows a timestamp in front of every log message.

Can `journalctl` be made to show the original kernel timestamps?  I want to check the precise timings for historical suspend/resume log messages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, yes it can.

```
$ journalctl -o short-monotonic -b
[    0.000000] alan-laptop kernel: microcode: microcode updated early to revision 0x2a, date = 2018-01-18
[    0.000000] alan-laptop kernel: Linux version 4.15.14-300.fc27.x86_64 (mockbuild@bkernel02.phx2.fedoraproject.org) (gcc version 7.3.1 20180303 (Red Hat 7.3.1-5) (GCC)) #1 SMP Thu Mar 29 16:13:44 UTC 2018
...
[    0.000000] alan-laptop kernel: x2apic: IRQ remapping doesn't support X2APIC mode
[    0.001000] alan-laptop kernel: ..TIMER: vector=0x30 apic1=0 pin1=2 apic2=-1 pin2=-1
[    0.006000] alan-laptop kernel: tsc: Fast TSC calibration using PIT
[    0.007000] alan-laptop kernel: tsc: Detected 2294.717 MHz processor
[    0.007000] alan-laptop kernel: Calibrating delay loop (skipped), value calculated using timer frequency.. 4589.43 BogoMIPS (lpj=2294717)
```

The timestamps match exactly with `dmesg`, even for suspend/resume.

(I do not attempt to nitpick whether this means they are CLOCK_BOOTTIME timestamps, as opposed to CLOCK_MONOTONIC timestamps; possibly the journald field name is confusing but it's exactly what I want).